# Swap / Sorting an array duplicates numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, swap

I am doing teaching myself c++ and I am learning to pass an array with ints entered by the user into another function where it sorts the array and spits it to the console. I tested passing the array itself and it works, however, my sorting does messes up somewhere as one number is duplicated some how. This is my code for swapping.

```
 while(1){
        swapped = 0;

        for(int i4 = 0; i4 < count; i4++){
            if(sdata[i4] > sdata[i4 + 1]){
                int temp = sdata[i4];
                sdata[i4] = sdata[i4 + 1];
                sdata[i4 + 1] = temp;
                swapped = 1;
            }
        }

        if(swapped == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is the values returned upon run.

```
 How many numbers? 5
[1] Please enter a value: 5
[2] Please enter a value: 3
[3] Please enter a value: 1
[4] Please enter a value: 2
[5] Please enter a value: 4
Original numbers: 5 3 1 2 4 
Swapped numbers: 1 2 3 3 4
```

I tried rewriting the swap in a new file just to test the swap itself, but I can't get it to work for some reason. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Assuming `count` is the number of entries in `sdata`, accessing `sdata[i4 + 1]` is outside the bounds of the array, resulting in Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use selection sort, In which the element swaps the maximum and minimum numbers in an array.

Here is the code :

```
    for(int i = 0; i<count-1; i++)
  {
    for(int j = i+1; j<count; j++)
    {
      if(sdata[i] > sdata[j])
        {
          int temp = sdata[i];
          sdata[i] = sdata[j];
          sdata[j] = temp;
        }
    }
  }
```